# Making a html alert using ajax, sql and php

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, ajax

I am trying to make some code where a click of a SQL html button can display a different SQL table as a popup. I have already gotten the variable from the table to pass through using this:

```php
echo "<td><a class='btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light black' onclick='partSearch(".$product.")' value='display'><i class='material-icons'>search</i></a></td>";
```

The 'part search' code is as follows:

```html
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function partSearch() {
            $.ajax({
            url: 'serv.php?id=<?php echo $product ?>',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(result){
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result)
                alert(obj)
            }
            })
        }
    </script>
```

Even though the variable is passed through to 'serv.php', I can't manage to get the sql data to be returned as a popup using alert. All I get is either nothing or [object, Object]. This is the SQL/php code:

```php
<?php   
    include 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM pr WHERE product_ID='".$id."'");// test this

    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $rows[] = $r;
    }


    echo json_encode($rows);
    ?>
```

Any help is appriciated

Comment: To `alert()`, you have to pass a string. You are getting a json string from the ajax request... In this case, you should not parse it. Did you try to simply `alert(result)` ?

Comment: Louys you are a legend. Thank you so much, I can't believe a simple fix makes this work :D

Comment: lol... If you wish to use the json string as a JS object, then parse it. No need for jQuery, Plain JS is: `let obj = JSON.parse(result);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
            function partSearch() {
                var product_id = "<?php echo $product; ?>";
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'serv.php?id=product_id',
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(result){
                      alert(result);
                    }
                })
            }
   </script>
```